# iOS 7: How to replace the standard view controller with a table view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller

The app is just one screen. I need the table view controller instead of the regular view controller so that I can have the table view style screen. I tried putting a table view controller on top of the view controller but when I run the simulator all I saw are blank rows.

Comment: Please provide some of your source code to give everyone a clearer picture of what you are trying to do. Also, use an introductory sentence describing the environment you are in.

Comment: There's no source code. This is just the first screen that doesn't yet have source code except the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't place `tableViewController` on top of `viewController`. Instead create a `tableViewController` object. `TableViewController` is a `viewController` with table.
Here is a simple [tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-ios-uitableviewcontroller) you can get help from.

Second way add a `UITableView` in `viewController` and implement `dataSource` and `delegate` method.  You can use this [tutorial](http://www.guilmo.com/how-to-create-a-simple-uitableview-with-static-data/)

Answer (score 0):

Hook up the TableView's `datasource` and `delegate`.

If you literally want JUST a tableview, if you're using storyboards, create a single-view app.  Delete the view controller, and create a table view controller.

Comment: I'm a beginner. how do I hook up the tableview's datasource and delegate?